# Make an escape sequences readable in a string

Tags: c, string, bash, echo

I'm trying to re-implement a Command line (Bash), and when i'm reading the command from the STDIN, it's literally a simple string, it doesn't treat the escape characters,
For example:

```
echo "hello \x0A World"
output : hello \x0A World

echo "hello \t world"
output : hello \t world
```

So i want to know how to handle the escape sequences correctly even if it's an Hexa or octal...
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Read the input character by character. When you encounter a `\` you perform a switch on the next character (didn't test the code, sorry):

```
char s[10000]; //you can do the buffer checking yourself, this is off-topic now
int i = 0;
char c = getchar();
while (c != '\n')
{
    if (c != '\\')
    {
        s[i++] = c;
        c = getchar();
        continue;
    }
    c = getchar();
    switch (c)
    {
        case 'n':
            s[i++] = '\n';
            break;
        case 't':
            s[i++] = '\t';
            break;
        //do this for every character you want to escape
        //for cases like 'x' and 'u', you will need to convert the next chunk of characters
        // to a number (in the specific base) and set s[i++] to that value.
        //if you encounter just digits (no letter), it's octal
    }
    c = getchar();
}
```